# Understanding JSON.stringify() on Redux Action?

Tags: redux, react-redux, immutability

I was trying to reset the data,  and want to go to initial state ,I know that the immutability playing major role in this part.

**Below is my store data (Flow Completed data)**

```
  animalSense: {
    selectedVision: 'dayLight',
    selectedState: 'california',
    viewedVisions: ['dayLightcalifornia', 'dayLightsouthAfrica', 'nightVisioncalifornia'],
    viewedAnimals: ['dog', 'cat']
  },
```

**I want to replace it with the below data**

```
  animalSense: {
    selectedVision: '',
    selectedState: '',
    viewedVisions: [''],
    viewedAnimals: []
  },
```

**I know the below action is the Straight and proper way to add initial data is**

```
export const RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES = 'actions/reset_animal_senses';

export default () => ({
  type: RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES,
  payload: {
    selectedVision: '',
    selectedState: '',
    selectedAnimal: '',
    viewedVisions: [''],
    viewedAnimals: []
  }
});
```

**But the above action maintaining the same stat**e

> **Below action is Working Solution but I don't know is this a Proper way**

```
export const RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES = 'actions/reset_animal_senses';

const data = JSON.stringify({
  selectedVision: '',
  selectedState: '',
  selectedAnimal: '',
  viewedVisions: [''],
  viewedAnimals: []
});
export default () => ({
  type: RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES,
  payload: JSON.parse(data)
});
```

**When we are using stringify the connectivity has been ended and the new state has been added but i don't know why this is not working without JSON.stringify()?**

**Reducer**

```
import { SELECT_VISION } from '../actions/select_vision_type';
import { CHANGE_ANIMAL_VIDEO_STATE } from '../actions/change_animal_video_state';
import { UPDATE_ANIMALS } from '../actions/update_animals';
import { RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES } from '../actions/reset_animal_senses';

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  let newState = state;
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_VISION:
      newState = { ...state, ...action.payload };
      break;
    case CHANGE_ANIMAL_VIDEO_STATE:
      newState = { ...state, ...action.payload };
      break;
    case UPDATE_ANIMALS:
      newState = { ...state, ...action.payload };
      break;
    case RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES:
      newState = { ...state, ...action.payload };
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return newState;
};
```

Comment: all store updates are supposed to be done in reducers. can you share your reducer that handles your reset action?

Comment: Yes Dude , my reducer is working perfectly , I have updated my question

Comment: Are all your properties not updating or just the arrays? Technically arrays are passed by reference and that could possibly play a role. Using the JSON.stringify() technique (or another example being lodash's _.deepClone) can and may in this situation be removing that reference between the child arrays in your action object. Just dealt with this in one of my projects. Just a thought.

Comment: not only the arrays The entire store has not been updated,  In my case i have added selectedAnimal in run time to reduce initial state properties ,  But when i reset i need that to validate ? is there any problem with this ? @joshua Dyck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spread Operator** in payload Solved this issue

```
export const RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES = 'actions/reset_animal_senses';
const data = {
    selectedVision: '',
    selectedState: '',
    selectedAnimal: '',
    viewedVisions: [''],
    viewedAnimals: []
};
export default () => ({
  type: RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES,
  payload: { ...data } // here is the solution
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, I'd do good amount of refactors to your reducer.

```
import { SELECT_VISION } from '../actions/select_vision_type';
import { CHANGE_ANIMAL_VIDEO_STATE } from '../actions/change_animal_video_state';
import { UPDATE_ANIMALS } from '../actions/update_animals';
import { RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES } from '../actions/reset_animal_senses';


const initialState = {
  selectedVision: '',
  selectedState: '',
  selectedAnimal: '',
  viewedVisions: [''],
  viewedAnimals: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // since all the cases have common code.
    case SELECT_VISION:
    case CHANGE_ANIMAL_VIDEO_STATE:
    case UPDATE_ANIMALS: {
        return { ...state, ...action.payload }
    }
    case RESET_ANIMAL_SENSES: {
        return { ...initialState }
    }
    default: {
        return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Try this reducer once. However, currently I don't have a clarity on why would it work with stringify in place.